# Find the version build numbers for SDL Tridion 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013

I need to find out the actual build number for Tridion 2013 SP1. Need info for corporate auditing prior to installation.

Answer (score 7):

The build number is '**7.1.0.66**'

You can find this by clicking on the SDL Tridion logo the CMS, I'm also sure this information can be found in the installation documentation. If you can't find the logo, you can also try the About entry in the left-hand slide-out menu. On my system, this can also be reached via `http://localhost/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=about`

**Full version details**

- Content Manager Build 7.1.0
- Content Manager Explorer Build 7.1.0.66
- Experience Manager Build 7.1.0.79
- Update version - SP1
- Content Delivery Version: 7.1
- Jar file build version (Handy for build systems like Maven): 7.1.0-STABLE.165

Comment: Rather than create a new answer, I've added the full list to your answer John.

Comment: Took the liberty of adding the proper build system version string for the CD Jars.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can find under the Home > Web content Management > About
there u will find out build number,

Answer (score 2):

As John says, clicking the logo in the CMS will get you a long way. If you need to audit the version of every deployed jar and dll, you will need mroe work. The problem here is that hotfixes often ship new versions of files.

There is [a script on Tridion Practice which automates the extraction of build versions from jar files](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/CheckVersionsOfContentDeliveryJars). This is a powershell script for use on Windows, but I've heard a rumour that customer support have a Bash version for use on *nix systems.

If you want to find the equivalent information for .NET assemblies, you can also do this easily enough from the powershell. Here's a quick and dirty version to demonstrate the principle. You'd probably need to modify it to suit your own purposes:

```
gci 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin' | ? {$_ -is [IO.FileInfo]} | % {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion + "`t" + $_.Name}
```

Comment: OP indicated he needed it prior to installation, so there is nowhere to click...

Comment: An audit prior to installation would presumably be checking the current versions of things. Otherwise, what would you be auditing?

Comment: Perhaps they want a detailed list of what versions will be installed exactly so that they can audit on that after the install, or maybe they want to Google for known issues with those versions. I wouldn't know, but fact is that is what the OP stated, if that is unclear, you should ask the OP for more info ;)

Comment: The OP said 'auditing prior to installation'. Unless they clarify that further, I'll assume that they intend to audit prior to installation.